# Need to add a phone number to a SQL query to add to a person's name and address

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Okay, so this is my situation.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I currently have a query that pulls a person's license number, address, first name, last name and ID. All I need to add to complete this is to add the phone number. I just recently came into this environment and I am not entirely sure what tables contain what data. There are almost 5000 tables and I simply don't have time to go through them.
How can I see if there are any relationships between the two tables?
I tried to do `where f.phn_int_id = a.psn_int_id`, but that does not work because the person id from table 1 does not match the phone id from table 2.

I should also mention that the table with the phone numbers contains only `phn_int_id`, `phn_ara_cd`, `phn_exc_no` and `phn_lcl_no`. The table with the person name contains `prsn_int_id`, `fst_nm`, `mid_nm` and `lst_nm`.

I am pulling a seperate address from a funtion, which is `person_address_line = dbo.fn_get_ent_pri_adr (b.psn_int_id, 'L'), person_address_csz = dbo.fn_get_ent_pri_adr (b.psn_int_id, 'C')`

*Note that b = our person name table.

**Note this is my first ever question, so I am going to probably miss some important information.

**Edit**
Everywhere that I have searched hasn't been able to help me solve my issue.

**Edit 2** This is the query, with names of tables changed to be *column 1, column 2* etc.

```
`SELECT a.car_gvr_ext_id, b.lst_nm, b.fst_nm, c.car_gvr_lic_no, e.cod_dtl_ds, concat(f.phn_ara_cd, f.phn_exc_no, f.phn_lcl_no) AS phn_no, person_address_line = dbo.fn_get_ent_pri_adr (b.psn_int_id, 'L'), person_address_csz = dbo.fn_get_ent_pri_adr (b.psn_int_id, 'C')
  FROM column1 a, column2 b, column3 c, column4 d, column5 e, column6 f
  WHERE a.psn_int_id = b.psn_int_id
  AND a.car_gvr_int_id = c.car_gvr_int_id
  AND a.car_gvr_int_id = d.car_gvr_int_id
  AND d.func_int_id = e.cod_dtl_int_id
  AND f.phn_int_id = a.car_gvr_int_id`
```

If I leave the code like this, I will get the phone number with phn_int_id = 1 to tie itself to car_gvr_int_id = 1 so on and so forth. The problem is that when I do that, I will get a line where someone from Florida will have a local number and someone with a local number will have an out of state number.

Comment: It might be helpful to post some data from your queries.

Comment: You can check from `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` for tables containing columns with certain name.

Comment: Take a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JamesZ That may be the exact direction I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to list columns from tables:

1- Using [Information Schema Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

**Example**

```
Select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

2- Using System tables [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) And [sys.Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) And [sys.schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176011.aspx)

**Example:**

```
SELECT cols.name as column_name, tbls.name as Table_name,schm.name as schema_name  FROM sys.columns  AS cols INNER JOIN sys.tables  AS tbls
ON cols.object_id = tbls.object_id INNER JOIN sys.schemas as schm ON tbls.schema_id = schm.schema_id
WHERE tbls.type = 'U'
```

When listing columns it is easier to work with your situation

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you for the answer!